# Running an application in the Background?

Tags: ios, background

My application runs in the Background (getting location updates) which I need to push to my server for every 10 seconds.

I have scheduled a timer which invokes a function in which the current location updates are captured and pushed to the server. This is running smoothly if the app is there in the foreground. When the app is moved to the background this functionality is running for 15 minutes after which I cannot see the method being invoked at all.

I know if an application is put into background it will be put into suspended state at any time. Also if another app running in the foreground requires memory at that time iOS may terminate some applications in the background. But in my case no application is running in the foreground as I have locked my device.

I also have an idea about `expirationHandler`. Would like to know if I can keep calling the function in the background without my app going into suspended state and Apple should accept that.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This exact question has been asked many times.  You can't just arbitrarily call your code every X seconds forever.  Apple doesn't allow that because it is a waste of CPU time and battery.  That's the end of the story.  What you *can* do is register for significant location updates and that will inform your app when the user has moved to a new "zone".

Answer (score 0):

You can add `App registers for location updates` under `Required background modes` in your plist.

Comment: Then be prepared to watch your app be rejected for not properly using the background mode.

Comment: If the app has the related feature of getting location updates and users know about it (the word related is defined by Apple), it would be survive

Comment: Then explain the abundance of "Wahhh my app got rejected for not using the background mode properly" questions on Stack Overflow.  Well, you have to make a very clear case for using it over the significant-change mode.

Comment: Sad, but true. Support with a clear description is a need....
And your code need to be handling lots of situation.

Answer (score 0):

The same scenario was also in my application i have set the uibackground mode in plist file and use that service from appdeligate and apple approved that application :)
Hope it may help you.